# EINVAL: invalid argument mkdir

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I have npm version 6.14 and node version 14.15.4
When I try to run the command for my angular app : npm run build I receive the error:

I have Windows 7 32-bit. I installed the latest Node.js 32 bit.

```
 95% emitting index-html-webpack-plugin EINVAL: invalid argument, mkdir 'C:\_APS\develop\target\public\C:\_APS\develop\Migrate\product\src\main\angular\src\app\pre\'
```

How does one resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in the version of WebPack (or maybe karma-webpack) being used by Angular.

It may be possible to work around this with some configuration settings:

```
// webpack configuration
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'temp'),
}
```

References:

- https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/12759
- https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/972b7f9bd1c608a0ce8794b4bed236cfffe72b2e/lib/Compiler.js#L796